# How can i copy a file from local commit on a different branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I committed a file on `master` branch but not pushed `remote`. Now i am working on `feature` branch and i want that file to be copied to `feature` branch from `master` branch.

How can i  do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout a specific file from another branch:

```
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```

The file will be copied from the branch *as is* into the working tree,
and automatically staged.

Note that the relative path from the working tree root is important. For example if you are in the root of the working tree (where there is the `.git` directory), then the path to the file in the branch must also be relative from the repository root. If you are in a subdirectory, then adjust accordingly.

To verify the correct path, the `ls-files` command can be helpful, for example:

```
git ls-files --with-tree master | grep file
```